# Function show div in <select> with localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I'm trying to learn about "localstorage", and so far I've managed to apply it to a select. But I'm having trouble getting it to show the "div" with Content One or Contet Two after page load. Localstorage saves the selected option, but the "**showDivOne**" and "**showDivTwo**" functions do not work, only after clicking the same option again. Is there any way to make these two div's appear without having to click again on some option?

```js
var init = function (){
  //an ugly warning to users without localStorage support
  if(!window.localStorage){
    $('body').prepend('Sorry, you browser does not support local storage');
    return false;
  }
  var sel = $('select'),
      but = $('button');
  
  var clearSelected = function(){
      sel.find(':selected').prop('selected', false);
  }
  
  if(localStorage.getItem('pref')){
    var pref = localStorage.getItem('pref');
    clearSelected();
    //set the selected state to true on the option localStorage remembers
    sel.find('#' + pref).prop('selected', true);
  }

  var setPreference = function(){
    //remember the ID of the option the user selected
    localStorage.setItem('pref', sel.find(':selected').attr('id'));
  };
  
  var reset = function(){
    clearSelected();
    localStorage.setItem('pref', undefined);
  }
  
  sel.on('change', setPreference);
  but.on('click', reset);
};
$(document).ready(init);


        
function showDivOne(divId, element){
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value == 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
}

function showDivTwo(divId, element){
  document.getElementById(divId).style.display = element.value == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
select, button {
  margin-top: .5em;
}


#one_div{
    display: none;
}



#two_div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select onchange="showDivOne('one_div', this); showDivTwo('two_div', this);">
  <option selected>Select an option</option>
  <option id="opt1" value="0">1</option>
  <option id="opt2" value="1">2</option>
</select>


<button>Reset preference</button>

<div id="one_div">Content One</div>
<div id="two_div">Content Two</div>
```

Comment: It looks to me as it's perfectly working

Comment: I rewrote this: https://jsfiddle.net/ye3ta075/ (edit: link fixed)

Comment: @cheesyMan When I refresh the page, localstorage displays the selected option, but does not trigger the "showDivOne/showDivTwo" function